# SMTP Gmail Server SSL Error

Tags: php, ssl, smtp

I used this coding to send mail using gmail, but am getting the below error, here when i removed the ssl part, its working, but i dint receive any emails(checked inside spam also). Any other problems ?

```
$mail = new phpmailer;
$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;// enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
$mail->SMTPAuth  = true; // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl"; // sets the prefix to the servier
$mail->Host  = "smtp.gmail.com"; // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->Port = 465;  // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username  = "un"; // GMAIL username
$mail->Password = "pwd"; // GMAIL password
$mail->SetFrom('test@gmail.com', 'Bharanidharan');
$mail->AddReplyTo("test@gmail.com","Vishal Kumar");
$mail->AddAddress("test@gmail.com","Bharani");
$mail->Subject = "Hey, check out";
$body = "hey, check email";
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
$address = "test@gmail.com";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "test");
if(!$mail->Send())
{
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else
{
echo "Message has been sent";
}
```

Comment: Where is the actual error message?

Comment: SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? (72165504) 
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable the mod_ssl in Apache (search the config file) and the openssl PHP extension (check php.ini)